# вставка картинки с prompt. По клику на блок выскакивает prompt в который затем копируется картинка

Tags: javascript

Решение для такой задачи

В HTML я написала такой код:

```
<div class="block1" onclick="imgUrl(event.target)"></div>
<div class="block2" onclick="imgUrl(event.target)"></div>
<div class="block3" onclick="imgUrl(event.target)"></div>
```

В JS:

```
function imgUrl(element) {
    let url = prompt('Write URL image');
    element.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + url + ')';
}
```

Comment: вы сами решили задачу задав вопрос, действуйте, никто за вас тут решать не будет

Comment: value какой не будь так - считать и записать в url - минус ни я ставил

Comment: минус мой (нужно 6 символов)

Comment: @meine не будь таким критичным - мы все учились - просто у топикстартера не у кого спросить

Comment: @MaximLensky, дело в том, что в интернете полно такой информации, на первых страницах изучения JS говорится про такую базу

Comment: @MaximLensky: если это учебная задача, то педагог должен был объяснить ранее. Если же это уже реальный проект, то непонятно, как можно браться не зная элементарного. Но, самое плохое - это то, что не заботятся об оформлении вопроса, не читают справку, не уважают ни новичков ни гуру.

Comment: @UModeL какой педагог (с третьего раза написал правильно) на youtube ? единственный источник с ценной инфой и там любой сенсей( даже писать не буду) берёт лавэ за обучение - нету лавэ смотри уроки и если дойдёт пользуйся

Comment: @MaximLensky: э-эх... Моё знакомство с компьютером началось с ZX в 1992 г. Бейсик и ассемблер - даже не помню откуда брали инфу. Но не из Интернета точно)) Потом сильно облегчила жизнь книжечка - https://zxpress.ru/book.php?id=132 и понеслось))... Мы учились, для того, чтобы знать, а не для того, чтобы на корочку сдать. Обленилась молодёжь...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я могу только с одним блоком показать - смотрим

```js
document.querySelector(".item").onclick = ev;

function ev() {
  let url = prompt("Вставьте url картинки");
  document.querySelector(".item").style.background = `url(${url})`;
  document.querySelector(".item").style.backgroundSize = "100% 100%";
}
```

```css
.item {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="item"></div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Далее по модели допишу. Спасибо!